# Complex boolean expression in python (django)

Tags: python, django, boolean

What does the following line mean?

```
return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <  now
```

It is at at the following link
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial05/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns true if the `self.pubdate` is in the past, but at most 1 day old.

In this context, it is a boolean expression returning `True` if the item (`self`) is recently published, `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

This is called a chained [comparison](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) and it is roughly equivalent to:

```
now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date and  self.pub_date <  now
```

From docs:

> `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y` and `y <= z`, except that `y` is
>   evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when
>   `x < y` is found to be false).

Here `now` is the current time and `now - datetime.timedelta(days=1)` is current time minus one day, So, the above expression will be `True`if the publication date lies in this time interval.